# Replacing function argument of type object by reference in php

Tags: php

I want to pass objects through a callback where they are completely replaced. Consider the following example:

```php
use stdClass;

$object = new stdClass();
$object->name = 'Initial name';

$callback = function ($original) {
    $modified = new stdClass();
    $modified->name = $original->name . ' modification.';

    $original = $modified;
};

$callback($object);

echo $object->name;

// Sees:  'Initial name'
// Wants: 'Initial name modification.
```

Is this possible? I tried setting the callback signature to `function (&$original)` but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: `$callback = function (&$original) { ... }` looks ok, can you paste the code sample that doesn't work?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/fiPg8 works…?!

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the function to accept the argument by reference.

```
$callback = function (&$original) {
```

[Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).